# How to show saved QR Code from database in asp.net report viewer

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, qr-code, rdlc, reportviewer

Here's the scenario:

I am generating and saving a QR Code to the database using https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode.

Now, I have to show it using a report viewer (rdlc) in asp.net.

The data type in the database is varchar(max) and one example of the value how it is saved is:

`data:image/png;base64,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`

My question is, how can I show this on a report using the asp.net report viewer?

This is how I can show it in the browser:

```
<img src="TheLongStringValueFromDatabase" />
```

I have tried to insert it as an image into the report viewer and set the following:

1. MIMEType to "image/pmg"
2. Source Database
3. Value (the value mentioned above)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

Instead of saving the image as varchar(max), I needed to save it as varbinary(max) to the database. In order to do that, I did the following:

```
Dim result As String() = qrCodeString.Split(New Char() {","c})    
Dim bytes() As Byte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(result(1))
```

where qrCodeString is the long string value I pasted in my original question.

Then, in the report viewer, I am inserting an "image" and setting the properties as before with the exception of the Value which now has data type of varbinary(max) and the QR Code is showing up now!